# JSONB Data Type Modification in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a doubt with modification of jsonb data type in postgres

### Basic setup:-

array=> ["1", "2", "3"] 
and now I have a postgresql database with an `id` column and a **jsonb datatype** column named lets just say `cards`.

```sql
  id    cards
-----+---------
1       {"1": 3, "4": 2}
```

thats the data in the table named `test`

### Question:

How do I convert the cards of `id->1` FROM `{"1": 3, "4": 2}` TO `{"1": 4, "4":2, "2": 1, "3": 1}`

#### How I expect the changes to occur:

From the `array`, increment by 1 all elements present inside the array that exist in the `cards jsonb` as a key thus changing {"1": 3} to {"1": 4} and insert the values that don't exist as a key in the `cards jsonb` with a value of `1` thus changing {"1":4, "4":2} to {"1":4, "4":2, "2":1, "3":1}
purely through postgres.

### Partial Solution

I asked a senior for support regarding my question and I was told this:-

> Roughly (names may differ): object keys to explode cards, array_elements to explode the array, left join them, do the calculation, re-aggregate the object. There may be a more direct way to do this but the above brute-force approach will work.

- So I tried to follow through it using these two functions `json_each_text()`, `json_array_elements_text()` but ended up stuck halfway into this as well as I was unable to understand what they meant by left joining two columns:-

```sql
SELECT jsonb_each_text(tester_cards) AS each_text, jsonb_array_elements_text('[["1", 1], ["2", 1], ["3", 1]]') AS array_elements FROM tester WHERE id=1;
```

[image: Showcase of Code]

#### TLDR;

- Update statement that checks whether a range of keys from an array **exist or not** in the jsonb data and automatically increments by 1 or inserts respectively the keys into the jsonb with a value of 1

Now it might look like I'm asking to be spoonfed but I really haven't managed to find anyway to solve it so any assistance would be highly appreciated

Comment: Your senior's right. They meant to start with `SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text(SELECT tester_cards FROM tester WHERE id=1) AS each_text, jsonb_array_elements_text('[["1", 1], ["2", 1], ["3", 1]]') AS array_elements;`. Now there's two things that you can `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Or, since this is for an update statement, you might want to start with a subquery this way: `SELECT tester.id, (SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text(tester.tester_cards) AS each_text, jsonb_array_elements_text('[["1", 1], ["2", 1], ["3", 1]]') AS array_elements) AS result FROM tester;`

Comment: Do you have an array `["1", "2", "3"]` or an array `[["1", 1], ["2", 1], ["3", 1]]`?

Comment: @Bergi the array isn't an issue as its simply input from my side so could be either :D

Comment: I'm sorry I still didn't understand how LEFT JOIN would work as for the previous part I've already managed to figure, but how am I supposed to progress ahead on it to have an update statement

Comment: I would say that you should return to the drawing board and devise a better data model for this; one that does not involve JSON. You will be happier in the long run.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thankyou for the suggestion I really don't think there could be a better way to handle the data with a relational database as its being used with multiple tables. However do suggest what else can be appropriate as a schema. Eitherways I would still have requested to know this knowledge of json manipulation due to it being useful in any future cases especially since I have not dived deep into postgres.

Comment: After thinking about it I have realized using an array with the index as the card id is also a possibility.. I will definitely look more into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key insight is that with `jsonb_each` and `jsonb_object_agg` you can round-trip a JSON object in a subquery:

```
SELECT id, (
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
  FROM jsonb_each(cards)
) AS result
FROM test;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=eef8b293b008e4730c96293f560ce2bf))</sup>

Now you can `JOIN` these key-value pairs against the `jsonb_array_elements` of your array input. Your colleague was close, but not quite right: it requires a full outer join, not just a left (or right) join to get all the desired object keys for your output, unless one of your inputs is a subset of the other.

```
SELECT id, (
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg(COALESCE(obj_key, arr_value), …)
  FROM jsonb_array_elements_text('["1", "2", "3"]') AS arr(arr_value)
  FULL OUTER JOIN jsonb_each(cards) AS obj(obj_key, obj_value) ON obj_key = arr_value
) AS result
FROM test;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=12672db77354b6fcce738c3d4320f674))</sup>

Now what's left is only the actual calculation and the conversion to an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE test
SET cards = (
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg(
    COALESCE(key, arr_value),
    COALESCE(obj_value::int, 0) + (arr_value IS NOT NULL)::int
  )
  FROM jsonb_array_elements_text('["1", "2", "3"]') AS arr(arr_value)
  FULL OUTER JOIN jsonb_each_text(cards) AS obj(key, obj_value) ON key = arr_value
);
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3c4d71af08f85a7cec3278b57cf8feab))</sup>

Comment: That is insightful, I will be sorting through all the information properly. Thankyou for the detailed explanation.

Comment: How would it be possible to have a different increment value I thought simply placing more of the same into the array would have that effect for example FROM jsonb_array_elements_text('["1", "2", "2", "5", "5", "5"]') AS arr(arr_value)
it didn't have any effect however with same +1 increment only once.

Comment: I guess for that you would need some sort of `GROUP BY` and a `count(…)`? `jsonb_object_agg` just ignores duplicate keys and keeps the last value. You can see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a791ff6f4cfaf5c290bf9fa6be33d642) what the non-aggregated tuples look like. However, instead of duplicating the key values in the array, I'd suggest you just pass `{"1": 1, "2": 2, "5": 3}` as an object